maping of memory into structure using ctypes in python
I am trying to map memory into structure but unable to get desired results. My memory is list of 32 bit values i.e.
[0x7E008000, 0x1234AAAA, 0xBBBBFFFF]

and I am trying to get this output.
ns: 0x7d008000
us: 0x1234
zs: 0xaaaabbbb
crc: 0xffff

with following code I am not getting correct "zs" value, and if I enable "crc" field I get error.
This is the output of below mentioned code
> ns: 0x7d008000
> us: 0x1234
> zs: 0xbbbbffff

Here is the code
   import struct
import ctypes

class MemoryParser:
    @classmethod
    def parse_memory(cls, memory):
        memory_bytes = bytearray()

        for word in memory:
            # Convert the word to little-endian bytes
            word_bytes = struct.pack(">I", word)
            # Extend memory_bytes with the word bytes in little-endian order
            memory_bytes.extend(word_bytes)

        # Create a ctypes pointer from the memory_bytes
        ubuffer = (ctypes.c_ubyte * len(memory_bytes)).from_buffer(memory_bytes)

        # Return the class instance created from the ctypes pointer
        return cls.from_buffer(ubuffer)

class Data(MemoryParser, ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("ns", ctypes.c_uint32),
                ("us", ctypes.c_uint16),
                ("zs", ctypes.c_uint32)]
                #("crc", ctypes.c_uint16)]

memory = [0x7E008000, 0x1234AAAA, 0xBBBBFFFF]

data = Data.parse_memory(memory)

print("ns:", hex(data.ns))
print("us:", hex(data.us))
print("zs:", hex(data.zs))
#print("crc:", hex(data.crc))

Update 1:
So I collected another data set and created fields but it fails again.
data set, example
[0x7E008000, 0x1234AAAA, 0xBBBBFFFC, 0xCCCDDEEE]

what will be the new class fields structure for expected data like below
v1 = 0x7E008000
v2 = 0x1234
v3 = 0xAAAABBBB
v4 = 0xFFF
v5 = 0xCCCC
v6 = 0xDD
v7 = 0xEEEE


In class Data you must add _pack_ = 1. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structure-union-alignment-and-byte-order

@MichaelButscher your suggestion resolve my issue, it works. Thanks. Can you post this as answer, so i can accept it.

I test with another data set and it failed. I updated the question.

The question isn't modified.

@MichaelButscher sorry now its updated

The update is something different as it contains values holding only some bits of a byte. It needs playing around with the bit field functionality of ctypes (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#bit-fields-in-structures-and-unions ) or using some bit juggling in Python. The behavior of ctypes here may even depend on the Python version. Maybe this is better moved to a new question. By the way: v7 output contains one E more than the input data has.

Thanks, sure I can move it to new question. Yes its by mistake i add extra E. Please answer the question with pack that you suggested, so i can close this question

ctypes follows the C rules of alignment of elements in a struct. For efficiency reasons, e.g. 32 bit (4 bytes) integers have their first byte at an address divisible by 4. To avoid additional padding bytes for proper alignment, add _pack_ = 1 to the ctypes structure (see documentation) like so:
class Data(MemoryParser, ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("ns", ctypes.c_uint32),
                ("us", ctypes.c_uint16),
                ("zs", ctypes.c_uint32),
                ("crc", ctypes.c_uint16)]

The error with the crc field appeared because the original structure had a size of 16 bytes due to 4 padding bytes and the raw input only had 12 bytes.

Here are structures for both examples.  _pack_ is needed for the first example, and bit fields are used for the second example.  Note that bit fields will pad as well for fields that don't nicely fit into the greater element used (in this case c_uint32 so I used properties to handle the edge cases:
import ctypes as ct
import struct

class Data1(ct.BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1  # eliminate default padding
    _fields_ = (('ns', ct.c_uint32),
                ('us', ct.c_uint16),
                ('zs', ct.c_uint32),
                ('crc', ct.c_uint16))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Data1(ns={self.ns:#x}, us={self.us:#x}, zs={self.zs:#x}, crc={self.crc:#x})'

    @classmethod
    def from_data(self, data):
        b = struct.pack('>LLL', *data)
        return Data1.from_buffer_copy(b)

# Bit fields are compiler-dependent.  This works for the MSVC compiler on Windows.
# Some bit fields cross element boundaries, hence the properties to combine them.
class Data2(ct.BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = (('v1', ct.c_uint32),
                ('v2', ct.c_uint32, 16),
                ('_v31', ct.c_uint32, 16),
                ('_v32', ct.c_uint32, 16),
                ('v4', ct.c_uint32, 12),
                ('_v51', ct.c_uint32, 4),
                ('_v52', ct.c_uint32, 12),
                ('v6', ct.c_uint32, 8),
                ('v7', ct.c_uint32, 12))

    @property
    def v3(self):
        return self._v31 << 16 | self._v32

    @v3.setter
    def v3(self, data):
        self._v31 = data >> 16
        self._v32 = data & 0xFFFF

    @property
    def v5(self):
        return self._v51 << 12 | self._v52

    @v5.setter
    def v5(self, data):
        self._v51 = data >> 12
        self._v52 = data & 0xFFF

    def __repr__(self):
        return (f'Data2(v1={self.v1:#x}, v2={self.v2:#x}, v3={self.v3:#x}, v4={self.v4:#x}, '
                      f'v5={self.v5:#x}, v6={self.v6:#x}, v7={self.v7:#x})')

    @classmethod
    def from_data(self, data):
        b = struct.pack('>LLLL', *data)
        return Data2.from_buffer_copy(b)

data1 = Data1.from_data([0x7E008000, 0x1234AAAA, 0xBBBBFFFF])
print(data1)

data2 = Data2.from_data([0x7E008000, 0x1234AAAA, 0xBBBBFFFC, 0xCCCDDEEE])
print(data2)
print(bytes(data2).hex(' ', 4))  # view the memory layout as DWORDs

data2.v3 = 0x12345678  # testing the property setters.
data2.v5 = 0xABCD
print(data2)
print(bytes(data2).hex(' ', 4))

Output:
Data1(ns=0x7e008000, us=0x1234, zs=0xaaaabbbb, crc=0xffff)
Data2(v1=0x7e008000, v2=0x1234, v3=0xaaaabbbb, v4=0xfff, v5=0xcccc, v6=0xdd, v7=0xeee)
7e008000 1234aaaa bbbbfffc cccddeee
Data2(v1=0x7e008000, v2=0x1234, v3=0x12345678, v4=0xfff, v5=0xabcd, v6=0xdd, v7=0xeee)
7e008000 12341234 5678fffa bcdddeee

